# Skeleton has 143 bones, but the maximum supported is 72

Tags: c#, animation, xna, 3d

I am using big models with alot of bones, and SkinnedEffect says that the maximum supported count of bones is 72, and I have 143, is there anything to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with an if statement located in SkinningData.cs : Do as search in that file for

```
if (bones.Count > SkinnedEffect.MaxBones)
{
                throw new InvalidContentException(string.Format(
                    "Skeleton has {0} bones, but the maximum supported is {1}.",
                    bones.Count, SkinnedEffect.MaxBones));
 }
```

and comment it out, and rebuild the skinnedmodelpipeline.dll

Comment: Isn't there a good reason for the current limit, then? It doesn't feed into a maximum limit in some other API, or run out of capacity in some other structure used, or massivly impact performance?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using .X models because I had this problem with it too.  I used FBXs instead and it seamed not to have this problem.

If you are using .fbx then ignore me!

Comment: I can confirm I am using .fbx files, and it is still happening.

Answer (score 0):

A Quick google yields:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Creating_a_Simple_3D_Game_with_XNA

This tutorial includes the blender side of things, but should cover what you need

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Creating_a_Simple_3D_Game_with_XNA/Rendering_Your_Model

This is the exact page you may be after.

Comment: I don't see anything about skeletons on those pages. Which part were you thinking of?

Comment: The guy edited the question, it was originally about importing animations. Should I delete the answer? It was pretty rude imo.

Original Question was: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10404060/1

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options:

1. Divide the mesh... (Obvius and simpler)
2. Pass the bone transform to the shader in other way. 
   Maybe using a texture.... and maybe not efficient... I don't know... It should be tested.